# How to create a file and insert a line in it using OS X terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal

How can I do the following using the terminal on OS X?

Create a file named `.inputrc` in a user's home directory and put this line in it:

`set completion-ignore-case On`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Quick Answer**

```
touch ~/.inputrc
echo "set completion-ignore-case On" >> ~/.inputrc
```

**Explanation**

First, create the file:

```
touch ~/.inputrc
```

Then, add the contents to the file:

```
echo "set completion-ignore-case On" >> ~/.inputrc
```

`touch` creates an empty file (assuming that the `~/.inputrc` file does not already exist). `echo` writes text to the "standard output" ("stdout" for short), which is normally your screen, but because of the redirection (`>>`), the output is redirected to `~/.inputrc`. This setup will append the line to the file.

If `~/.inputrc` already exists and you want to *erase* (clobber) its contents, and then write the line into it (i.e., create a file with *only* this line of text), do:

```
echo "set completion-ignore-case On" > ~/.inputrc
```

The single arrow (`>`), a.k.a. "greater than" symbol, tells `echo` to create a file with only the given text as the contents of the file, instead of writing the contents to the end of the file. (Actually, `echo` does not create the file; the shell creates the file, discarding any existing contents, and the `echo` command writes the new contents.)

---

If you use the first approach (with the `>>`) and you find that the line that you added is smushed onto the previous line, e.g.,

```
some stuff here
some more stuff hereset completion-ignore-case On
```

then you need to edit the file to fix it.
This would happen if the last line of the pre-existing file ended with a textual character rather than a "newline" character (i.e., an end-of-line marker). This is common for `.TXT` files on Windows, but rare on *nix.

If you somehow realize in advance that your `.inputrc` file has pre-existing contents that do not end with a newline,
then you should use this `echo` statement instead:

```
echo -e "\nset completion-ignore-case On" >> ~/.inputrc
```

The `\n` before the phrase is interpreted as a newline character, so a newline is added after the previous contents and before the new stuff you want to add.

Or, slightly more typing but much more readable,

```
echo "" >> ~/.inputrc
echo "set completion-ignore-case On" >> ~/.inputrc
```

or

```
(echo ""; echo "set completion-ignore-case On") >> ~/.inputrc
```

which do the same thing; i.e., provide the missing newline character to the existing text, and then add the `set completion-…` command after that.

Comment: There is no reason to use the `touch` command here; `echo "…" >> ~/.inputrc` is quite enough.

Comment: Unless the file you want to append to is not existed.

Comment: @Baron: No, `echo "…" >> ~/.inputrc` will create the file if it doesn't exist.  Except for pathological cases, like `~` doesn't exist, you don't have write permission in `~`, or the file system is full; and, in such cases, `touch` won't help.  `touch` is completely superfluous here.

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is:

```
echo "set completion-ignore-case On" >> ~/.inputrc
```

`echo` simply echos the text given to it through the normal output channel (stdout)

the `>>` writes the stdout output from the left hand command to the right hand file, which in your case is `~/.inputrc`

`~/` is the same as `/home/your_username/`